# How do I resolve the React app error for npm run build "Failed to compile. Failed to minify the bundle."?

Tags: reactjs

I ran 'create-react-app frontend' (loaded result into [repository](https://github.com/calycolor/create-react-app_frontend) if that helps) cd into frontend then successfully ran 'npm run test', but when I ran 'npm run build' I received the following error:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Failed to minify the bundle. Error: static/js/main.6eb16068.chunk.js from Terser
TypeError: Cannot read property 'minify' of undefined
    at compiler.run (/Users/jo/sdk/my-app/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js:169:23)
    at finalCallback (/Users/jo/sdk/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:210:39)
    at hooks.done.callAsync.err (/Users/jo/sdk/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:226:13)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/jo/sdk/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/jo/sdk/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at onCompiled (/Users/jo/sdk/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:224:21)
    at hooks.afterCompile.callAsync.err (/Users/jo/sdk/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:553:14)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/jo/sdk/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/jo/sdk/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at compilation.seal.err (/Users/jo/sdk/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:550:30)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/jo/sdk/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/jo/sdk/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at hooks.optimizeAssets.callAsync.err (/Users/jo/sdk/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1295:35)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/jo/sdk/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/jo/sdk/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at hooks.optimizeChunkAssets.callAsync.err (/Users/jo/sdk/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1286:32)
Read more here: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/troubleshooting#npm-run-build-fails-to-minify

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jo/.npm/_logs/2019-02-02T22_35_37_563Z-debug.log
```

This is the log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.15.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~prebuild: my-app@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~build: my-app@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~build: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/jo/sdk/my-app/node_modules/.bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/spark/bin:/usr/local/scala/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Applications/DevDesktop/tools:/usr/local/bin
9 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~build: CWD: /Users/jo/sdk/my-app
10 silly lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts build' ]
11 silly lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: my-app@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid my-app@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/jo/sdk/my-app
16 verbose Darwin 17.7.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v10.15.1
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error my-app@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

When I searched I found this **[bug fix](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5250)**.

However, I do not know what that means...how would I implement the fix that is mentioned?  I read about the [minify issue](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/troubleshooting#npm-run-build-fails-to-minify), but my package.json file shows react-scripts@>=2.0.0:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this to your dependencies in your package.json: `"terser": "3.14.1",`

The problem comes from the current version of terser (3.16), so by now it's needed to keep the version fixed.

Comment: Yes, that worked, I also had to run 'npm install terser@3.14.1 --save-dev' because I am on "node": "10.15.1", and "npm": "6.4.1" as mentioned in this bug report: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6334

Comment: thanks for the pointer. It showed us our lockfile should have prevented this (but we were not using it event though we thought we did)